# Prefetch React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Is there more to the React Native Prefetch feature than simply calling that URL like this:

```
var prefetchTask = Image.prefetch(IMAGE_PREFETCH_URL);
```

Attempting to load an image into cache so when I choose to display it into my app it is quick, and I am using the code above, however I can't really notice any sort of load speed difference, where it feels like it should definetly have been quicker...

I am using Android.. It seemed like this was available for both platforms..

Any other solutions for caching images?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it, but it might be that the delay you are noticing is the time it takes the app to render the image, and not to download it (which might be quite faster, specially if you are running your app in debug mode). You can try to time it using the `onLoadStart`/`onLoadEnd` methods of the `<Image>` (see the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/image.html#onloadend) and the [example](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/image.html#examples)). As for other caching solutions, you might want to check some third-party packages, such as [react-native-cacheable-image](https://github.com/jayesbe/react-native-cacheable-image) or [react-native-cache-image](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-cache-image).

Comment: oh Hmm, that is a good point.. Maybe the issue is simply the rendering.. looking at an app like snapchat, which seems to let you switch pictures with no noticable delay is something I am trying to figure out how

Comment: What is the size of your images? You might want to look into using smaller images on views. I noticed a performance improvement once I did that on some images loaded through an image picker (going from more than 2000px wide to ~400). Of course, this might not suit you if you are trying to render high-resolution images.

Comment: Definitely smaller than that. I have been trying to improve on basically a slideshow implementation. It is definitely the rendering.. is there no work around such as rendering an image behind the other one? Or are you sorta doomed

Comment: Have you tried running the app on release mode on a device? The debug mode really slows the application down, and it might be that your emulator is also not performing as well as a real phone would.